# Am I able to deduce a point on a curve that I don't have raw data for?

Tags: r

I have created a curve using a handful of x and y values. I would like to find the y value (VWC) associated with the x value (Pressure) when x equals 0.33, however, I do not have an actual observation at that value. Is there a way to determine what that would be?

Here is my dataset:

```
structure(list(Depth = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5"), class = "factor"), Pressure = c(0, 0.01, 
0.02, 0.05, 0.1, 0.2), meanVWC = c(0.4336082346, 0.2846267492, 
0.2047628536, 0.128102597, 0.1031056212, 0.0899228308)), row.names = c(NA, 
-6L), class = c("grouped_df", "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), groups = structure(list(
    Depth = structure(1L, .Label = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5"), class = "factor"), 
    .rows = list(1:6)), row.names = c(NA, -1L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), .drop = TRUE))
```

Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Sure it's possible, you can use: https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/stats/versions/3.6.1/topics/approxfun

Answer (score 0):

You have an exponential relationship between your parameters:

[image: exponential relationship]

And you basically want to estimate the asymptote (extrapolating Pressure > 0.2). It turns out that R has built in asymptote estimation for exactly this purpose:

```
xy <- sortedXyData(df$Pressure, df$meanVWC, df)

NLSstRtAsymptote(xy)
```

```
[1] 0.04696216
```

Edit: if you think 0.33 isn't that close to the asymptote, you're going to need to fit an exponential, which might be challenging with so little data and a defined intercept.